# C makefile, in CCS, "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c, makefile, target, code-composer

I am new to makefiles, so please bear with me. I tried to edit an automatically generated makefile in Code Composer Studios, but I'm getting an error.
Here is an excerpt from the makefile

```
# All Target
all: makefile_project_test1.out
    @echo ''
    @echo '============================'
    @echo 'APPLICATION BUILD SUCCESSFUL'
    @echo '============================'
    @echo ''
    @myfaketarget

# Other Targets
.PHONY: myfaketarget
myfaketarget:
    echo "TEST MY FAKE TARGET"
```

And here is the error message that prints out.

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, myfaketarget, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone shed some light on this, and help me to get this to compile cleanly? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@myfaketarget` line is a command line. You are telling make to run a system command with the name `myfaketarget`. That isn't a binary/application/etc. though so the system (Windows) cannot do that.

If you want the `myfaketarget` target to be run as a prerequisite of the `all` target then you want to list it next to `makefile_project_test1.out` on the `all: makefile_project_test1.out` line.

If you want that target to be run *after* the rest of that `all` body is run (i.e. where that `@myfaketarget` line is) then you need to manually run `make myfaketarget` yourself (possibly as `$(MAKE) myfaketarget` depending on make version).

Comment: That was it! Thank you! My intention was to have that run in the middle of the body of "all". $(MAKE) myfaketarget did the trick! Thanks!